# Anacron fails to open folder cron.daily / cron.weekly

Tags: linux, cron

Recently I switched from user-specific anacrontab ( using -t ) to the global-one. Now each day anacron drops me a message (email to root) that it failed to open the cron.daily folder:

```
Subject: Anacron job 'cron.daily' on myComputer
Message: run-parts: failed to open directory /etc/cron.daily: No such file or directory
```

The rsnapshot-jobs run normally, however the cron-related jobs dont.
Here my anacrontab `/etc/anacrontab`

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron
#
# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root

# These replace cron's entries
# days to wait - delay in minutes - job-name - command to execute
1   5   cron.daily  run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7   10  cron.weekly run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly    15  cron.monthly    run-parts--report /etc/cron.monthly
1   5   rsnapshot.day   /usr/local/bin/doBackup.sh daily
7   30  rsnapshot.week  /usr/local/bin/doBackup.sh weekly
```

And here the output of `ls -rtl /etc | grep cron` to see the folder permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      722 Jul  3  2012 crontab
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Sep 11  2015 cron.hourly
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Sep 11  2015 cron.monthly
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Sep 11  2015 cron.weekly
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Jan 25 16:04 cron.daily
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      858 Mar 21 10:49 anacrontab
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Mar 21 10:57 cron.d
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root     4096 Mar 21 10:57 cron-apt
```

( Not enough reputation to create tag 'anacron' )

**Edit1**:

Additional Information. If I copy the line which seems to produce the message and execute it as root, there is no problem ( I added -v to see some output, however it as well works without):

```
root@myComputer:/etc# run-parts -v /etc/cron.daily
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/0anacron
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/apt
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/aptitude
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/bsdmainutils
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/cracklib-runtime
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/dpkg
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/exim4-base
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/man-db
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/mlocate
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/passwd
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest
root@myComputer:/etc#
```

**Edit2**:

Finally I know what caused anacron to act that wired. It's about the line-endings in the anacrontab:

```
sed -n l anacrontab
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron\r$
...
```

A healthy anacrontab should not have the `\r` at the line-endings ( these are Carriage Returns ) .. actually I have no idea how they came there.

So this is a bug in anacron. Either anacron should completly refuse to execute such a malformated file, or it should just eat the Carriage Returns and work like expected. I filed the bug to the debian bugtracker. The current state of the bug can be checked here:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=821081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to remove all jobs but cron.daily and test it with "anacron -T"?
As I can see, your **rsnapshot.day** and **cron.daily** jobs run simultaneously with the same delay. May be this causes conflict with access rights.

Comment: anacron -T only complains about blank lines which are skipped, so the format seems to be fine. I will try to change the delay of the rsnapshot jobs in order to see if it matters.

Comment: Does not matter, problem still persists

Comment: Recently I also faced problems with anacron - it didn't run daily and weelky jobs at all, but run monthly jobs for unknown reasons. I completely removed anacron with `apt-get purge anacron` and installed it again. Then it started working properly. May be reinstalling will help you.

Comment: Ok, done. I deleted `/etc/anacrontab` and purged the package ... I did not modify the new `/etc/anacrontab` so far ... I'll report back tomorrow, on the next cron.daily attempt :)

Comment: YAY! Seems like it does the trick ! According to `/var/log/cron.log` some daily stuff was executed. ( No upgrades, so no mail to root)  I will now add the rsnapshot-lines and re-check tomorrow if that as well works.

Comment: Ok, as well backups work normally, thanks Sir, the 50rep is yours ! I will take a try for the old anacrontab tomorrow .. I still want to know what was wrong to be able to report a bug to anacron.

Comment: Congratulations :)

Comment: Ok, after some trial & error with the old, broken anacrontab I figured out what was the problem ... I 'll add it in the main-post.

Comment: Heh, I've was thinking of that from the very beginning, but couldn't imagine how such windows-like line endings can came to Linux file. Thank you for your investigation.

Comment: I dont run any windows-system, so I dont know exactly what happened to the file... maybe I sent it via email to my work-computer(as well debian) and back some years ago to use the same config. Possibly a mail client, or the mail server of the company I work for could be blamed.